# How use HttpClient class to request multiple URLs without losing the relation between the URL

Tags: rest, http, async-await, dart

I would like to request some URLs and combine the result with the requested data.

For example I would like to call https://postman-echo.com/time/leap to find out if a year is a leap. For this I have to use the parameter timestamp like:
https://postman-echo.com/time/leap?timestamp=2016-01-01
which returns true.

In this case I have data "2016-01-01" and the result "true". After combining both I have:

```
{2016-01-01: true}
```

To check multiple dates I would like to call the URL multiple times and get the result like :

```
{2015-01-01: false}
{2016-01-01: true}
{2017-01-01: false}
```

But my implementation failed to combine the data value and I can't figure out why. I get the result

```
{2016-01-01: false}
{2017-01-01: false}
{2015-01-01: false}
```

Here the the code, I tried to solve my Problem.
https://dartpad.dartlang.org/78049ae322d87cb73588e8cec28d0bdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a race condition, `_url` and `_responseBody` probably shouldn't be member variables.

I'd make `_url` a local variable and `_sendRequest` could actually return the `responseBody`:

```
Future<Map<String, List>> sendRequestForLeapyear(String year) async {
  var url = "${_address}/time/leap?timestamp=${year}";
  var responseBody = await _sendRequest(url);
  var responseMap = JSON.decode(responseBody);
  var isLeap = responseMap['leap'];
  return {year : isLeap};
}

Future<String> _sendRequest(String url) async {
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  return await client.getUrl(Uri.parse(url)).then((HttpClientRequest request) {
    request.persistentConnection = false;
    return request.close();
  }).then((HttpClientResponse response) {
    return response.transform(UTF8.decoder).join("").then((String body) {
      return body;
    });
  }).catchError((e) {
    throw new StateError("failed to poll $_url because: $e");
  }).whenComplete(client.close);
}
```

**Edit**: also you misspelled the API endpoint's parameter `timestamp` :D

Comment: It failed because _sendRequest should return a Future but when I change the return value to Future<String> I will get the error The null object does not have a getter 'length'.

Comment: I fixed up the code and found that you misspelled the parameter for the API. `timestamp` vs `timespamp`